# Access-Control-Allow-Headers is set but impossible to get needed custom response header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, fetch-api, response-headers

I get some data from an endpoint (the origin and endpoint domains are different).
I need to get some information from the custom response header. On the server side, this custom response header was added in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header.
Applied response headers. Response body is ReadableStream

```
    Some-Header: attachment; filename="some-name.tar"
    Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Some-Header

    Date: Thu, 03 Nov 2022 17:11:04 GMT
    Content-Type: application/octet-stream
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Connection: keep-alive
    X-Request-ID: d331a838-b22b-41c1-a5c9-bf3461129a97
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    X-RateLimit-Limit: 50
    X-RateLimit-Remaining: 49
    X-RateLimit-Reset: 1667495466
    X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
    X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
    X-Download-Options: noopen
    Surrogate-Control: no-store
    Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
    Pragma: no-cache
    Expires: 0
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

When I try to get this header on the client side, I get only some default headers.

```
function fetchData(path, options) {
    return fetch(`${API_URL}${path}`, options)
        .then(parseResponse(path));
}

const response = yield call(
    fetchData,
    url,
    requestOptions,
);

console.log(response.headers && Array.from(response.headers))
```

Did not return "Some-Header"

```
[
    [
        "cache-control",
        "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate"
    ],
    [
        "content-type",
        "application/octet-stream"
    ],
    [
        "expires",
        "0"
    ],
    [
        "pragma",
        "no-cache"
    ]
]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used the wrong header. I should use the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers

Answer (score -1):

`Access-Control-Allow-Headers` allows *incoming* headers. What you send out from the server is always allowed.

As for the response, you will need to add the header and a value server-side.

Comment: The server sent some data by some endpoint. But additional information is stored in the response header of this endpoint.

Comment: What does the raw response look like? Does it actually include the header?

Comment: Edited the initial post. Applied raw response headers. Response body is ReadableStream.
The request info:
Request URL: http://192.168.242.128:8100/915239772/download
Request method: GET
Status code: 200 OK
Remote address: 192.168.242.128:8100
Referrer policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin